# How to filter data from Salesforce in Qlik Sense

Tags: filter, salesforce, load, qliksense

I'm completely new to Qlik Sense and also with the coding syntax used in the data load editor.

I select the `Account` object from Salesforce through the connector and I select the fields `Account ID`, `Country` and `LastActivityDate`. Then I was surprised I could not filter that object by, for example, `Country = Netherlands`.

Now, I tried to do something in the sense of: `WHERE Country__c="Netherlands"`, but of course it's not as easy as that.

I need to implement these filters:

1. **Country__c = Netherlands**
2. **LastActivityDate is from 1st of May and beyond**

Comment: The SF Connector generates an SOQL statement and then loads it via a load script.  You should be able to filter at either place (but much more efficient to filter in the SOQL part).  Does your WHERE statement work in the SF Developer Console?

Comment: I've never used the SF Developer Console, so I'm not sure how to test it. In theory, it should work. It does work on a different table, but not this one.

Comment: Have you tried single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Hate to be vague but these links should be of help.

Filtering data from data connectors : 
But Qlik disclaims that the ability to filter is not available for all connectors.

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/LoadData/Filter-data.htm

If all else fails, load everything and make use of this little tool. Be weary of getting dependent on it.

http://tools.qlikblog.at/SetAnalysisWizard/QlikView-SetAnalysis_Wizard_and_Generator.aspx?sa=